# Pointer increment is different from integer increment?

Tags: c

I wrote this code and observed an interesting behavior, if any one can comment why this is happening it would be great!

```
int main()
{
    char *name = "ABCDEF";
    int i = 0;

    printf("\n Base address of name %u", name);
    printf("\n Address ++name %u", ++name);
    printf("\n Address name + 1 %u", name + 1);
    printf("\n Adddress name +2 %u", name + 2);
    printf("\n Base address of name %u", name);

    printf("\n i %d", i);
    printf("\n i+1 %d", i + 1);
    printf("\n i+2 %d", i + 2);
    printf("\n i+3 %d", i + 3);
    printf("\n i %d", i);

    return 0;
}
```

The last line should return the original pointer value which is not happening, also unlike the integer variable where the addition happens with the original value of 0, in case of the pointer it is happening from the previous value.

[image]

Comment: The problem is not the difference between pointer and integer, but that you are using different operations. `++i` is different from `i + 1`. The former modifies the variable, the latter just returns the incremented value.

Comment: Note: pointer format is `%p`

Comment: Don't post pictures of text here. Post the text.

Answer (score 2):

About prefix increment operators in N1570 (Emphasis mine):

> 6.5.3.1 Prefix increment and decrement operators
>
> Semantics
>
> 2 **The value of the operand of the prefix ++ operator is incremented.**
>   The result is the new value of the operand after incrementation. The
>   expression ++E is equivalent to (E+=1).

That is, `name` became `name + 1` after `printf("\n Address ++name %u", ++name);` is executed, giving you `4210689` in the last line.

---

BTW, to print the value of a pointer to an object, namely the address of that object, you should use `printf("\n Address ++name %p", (void *)++name);` instead (pointers to functions are excluded, however).

Answer (score 1):

The last line

```
printf("\n Base address of name %u",name);
```

where the contents of `name` are printed does *not* print its initial value,
as in between the post-increment operator `++name` is used, which changes the content of `name` as a side-effect.